# Modifying C# dictionary value

Tags: c#, data-structures, collections

I'm a C++ expert, but not at all for C#. I created a `Dictionary<string, STATS>`, where `STATS` is a simple `struct`. Once I built the dictionary with initial `string` and `STATS` pairs, I want to modify the dictionary's `STATS` value. In C++, it's very clear:

```
Dictionary<string, STATS*> benchmarks;
Initialize it...

STATS* stats = benchmarks[item.Key];
// Touch stats directly
```

However, I tried like this in C#:

```
Dictionary<string, STATS> benchmarks = new Dictionary<string, STATS>();

// Initialize benchmarks with a bunch of STATS
foreach (var item in _data)
  benchmarks.Add(item.app_name, item);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, STATS> item in benchmarks)
{
  // I want to modify STATS value inside of benchmarks dictionary.
  STATS stat_item = benchmarks[item.Key];
  ParseOutputFile("foo", ref stat_item);

  // But, not modified in benchmarks... stat_item is just a copy.
}
```

This is a really novice problem, but wasn't easy to find an answer.

**EDIT**: I also tried like the following:

```
  STATS stat_item = benchmarks[item.Key];
  ParseOutputFile(file_name, ref stat_item);
  benchmarks[item.Key] = stat_item;
```

However, I got the exception since such action invalidates Dictionary:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
  at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Enumerator.MoveNext()
  at helper.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\dev\\helper\Program.cs:line 75
```

Comment: Ugh, you should have left those capital letters behind in the C++ world. It looks awful in C#. Microsoft's naming guidelines suggest using Pascal case.

Comment: A struct is value type, thus this is the same then declaring a local double, thus the new stat_item is a copy of the dictionary record. If STATS would be a class, then it is a reference and then it would work.

Comment: This is a very simple toy parsing program. :D Actually, I still love to write code in Windows C++ style, but now I am forced to follow Google's guideline... Sorry for that!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your `STATS` is indeed a `struct`, that means it's a **value type**, so where you do this:

```
STATS stat_item = benchmarks[item.Key];
ParseOutputFile("foo", ref stat_item);
```

Your `stat_item` is a **copy** of the value located at `benchmarks[item.Key]`. Thus when you pass it as a `ref` parameter to `ParseOutputFile`, only the **copy** is modified.

In the C++ code you posted, notice you would do what you're trying to accomplish here by using a pointer.

For .NET, the solution is simple: change `STATS` to a **reference type** (a `class` rather than `struct`). Then your local `stat_item` variable will be a reference to the same object referenced by the value of `benchmarks[item.Key]`.

Comment: Thanks, it just works well. I didn't know that such semantics.

Answer (score 2):

You should just change STATS to a class.  Then you wouldn't need the ref keyword and the object would change.

The usual advice in C# is to use classes unless you are absolutely certain you *need* a struct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
STATS stat_item = benchmarks[item.Key]; 
ParseOutputFile("foo", ref stat_item); 
benchmarks[item.Key] = stat_item;
```

Note that even if STATS is a class, then updating the reference (as is implied by the ref keyword) will only update the local reference stat_item, not the value in the dictionary.

For example, the following code will modify the value in the dictionary if STATS is a class (but in this case the ref keyword is not needed and should be removed):

```
ParseOutputFile(string foo, ref STATS statItem)
{
    statItem.SomeProperty = ...
}
```

But the following will only affect the local variable and won't update the dictionary value, even if STATS is a class:

```
ParseOutputFile(string foo, ref STATS statItem)
{
    statItem = new STATS();
    ...
}
```